# Infinite bug when i install vs2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When I install vs a message like the one in the image appears and it stays on forever if I forcefully close it and start the installed visual studio, it has errors it doesn't let me create projects and it's not very solid

[image: Infinity blug]

And tried to repair the installation and the error persists, after repairing it it reopens the message and stays there infinitely. I tried to install the vs 2019 and it works perfectly but I need the 2022

Comment: This question has nothing to do with C# so the tag has been removed.

Comment: If a repair didn't work, the next step would to uninstall, restart and install again. It may not help but it's one of the steps to go through.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I already did it and a lot

Comment: What means "forever"? It really may take 10 mins or so, if your computer isn't the latest and greatest any more.

Comment: @PMF I left it 2 days and 1 night, I have good internet and a good computer, and if it were the performance of my PC, the same or similar would happen with vs 2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the solution to my problem, I had 2 hard drives I tried downloading it on the other one and everything worked without problems

Answer (score 0):

Had the same thing, loaded the new VS2022 OK, loaded a project Ok.  But still the "getting ready...." message persisted.  Task Manager, end all VS2022 entries, and it loaded OK. Message gone.

Answer (score -1):

there are a few things that can help you fix it...

- Redownload the installer
- Restart your PC...
- see if any of your dependencies are malfunctioning or not properly installed ....

- These should fix your issue , if not , let me know ....

Comment: already tried that and nothing